# Import matplotlib as plt (UnicodeDecode Error)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Brand new to python.  I've searched for this problem but the material out there is way far-ranging and over my head.  I'm hoping I have a more specific issue with this 'traceback'?  (traceback is the error code?).

Having the following issue when I attempt "import matplotlib as plt".  From the study on the matter it could be a font with e' or o: or something of that nature?  Is there a file I have to delete within the folder structure?

I'm set up Jupyter with Anaconda2.  And as far as I can tell it's using python 3.5.  Operating system is windows 7.

---

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-eff513f636fd> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
     27 from cycler import cycler
     28 import matplotlib
---> 29 import matplotlib.colorbar
     30 from matplotlib import style
     31 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>()
     32 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     33 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
---> 34 import matplotlib.collections as collections
     35 import matplotlib.colors as colors
     36 import matplotlib.contour as contour

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in <module>()
     25 import matplotlib.artist as artist
     26 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 27 import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
     28 import matplotlib.path as mpath
     29 from matplotlib import _path

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in <module>()
     60 
     61 import matplotlib.tight_bbox as tight_bbox
---> 62 import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
     63 from matplotlib.path import Path
     64 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation, warn_deprecated

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py in <module>()
     13 from matplotlib.path import Path
     14 from matplotlib import rcParams
---> 15 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
     16 from matplotlib.ft2font import FT2Font, KERNING_DEFAULT, LOAD_NO_HINTING
     17 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in <module>()
   1419                 verbose.report("Using fontManager instance from %s" % _fmcache)
   1420         except:
-> 1421             _rebuild()
   1422     else:
   1423         _rebuild()

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in _rebuild()
   1404     def _rebuild():
   1405         global fontManager
-> 1406         fontManager = FontManager()
   1407         if _fmcache:
   1408             pickle_dump(fontManager, _fmcache)

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in __init__(self, size, weight)
   1042         #  Load TrueType fonts and create font dictionary.
   1043 
-> 1044         self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
   1045         self.defaultFamily = {
   1046             'ttf': 'Bitstream Vera Sans',

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in findSystemFonts(fontpaths, fontext)
    311             fontpaths = [fontdir]
    312             # now get all installed fonts directly...
--> 313             for f in win32InstalledFonts(fontdir):
    314                 base, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    315                 if len(ext)>1 and ext[1:].lower() in fontexts:

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in win32InstalledFonts(directory, fontext)
    228                         continue
    229                     if not os.path.dirname(direc):
--> 230                         direc = os.path.join(directory, direc)
    231                     direc = os.path.abspath(direc).lower()
    232                     if os.path.splitext(direc)[1][1:] in fontext:

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\ntpath.pyc in join(path, *paths)
     83         if result_path and result_path[-1] not in '\\/':
     84             result_path = result_path + '\\'
---> 85         result_path = result_path + p_path
     86     ## add separator between UNC and non-absolute path
     87     if (result_path and result_path[0] not in '\\/' and

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I'm guessing on the fonts on your system has unicode in the file path or name and fontmanager.py doesn't like that.  Can you try running this on a different system?

Comment: Only computer I have, I'm afraid.  What is fontmanager.py and can it be opened to see what's inside?  I mean, nothing obvious about the Anaconda2 folder structure indicates the use of an unusual character?  Should I delete the file "fontmanager.py"?.

Comment: You could try re-installing matplotlib, but I meant that I think you have a TTF font in your windows system where the path has a non-ascii character (my guess).  You can edit line 230 of font_manager.py and add a print statement to check the values of directory and direc, to see if they are strict ASCII.  If not, then move that font out of the path

Comment: Sorry, I should have indicated what I already done.  I uninstalled all software, reapplied it, tried Anaconda3, back to Anaconda2, upgraded to most recent matplotlib, all to no avail.  How do I open a *.py file?  What is a *.py file?

Comment: A *.py file is a python script ( font_manager.py should be a standard python module / script).  It is a basic text file.  You may want to take a step back to familiarize yourself with python a little more before proceeding.  suggested topics: the os.path function and print statements and unicode.